# Cannot add modfiers to objects, don't appear on menu

Tags: modifiers

[image: Screenshot]

I'm able to apply them on some modifiers, the drop down tab to show all objects will ignore the ball, this seems to apply only to the modifier icons being red. I'm trying to apply a curve to the object. Do I need to apply something else beforehand?

On windows 10 x64, blender 2.92.2

Comment: I'm able to apply them on some modifiers, the drop down tab to show all objects will ignore the ball, this seems to apply only to the modifier icons being red. I'm trying to apply a curve to the object. Do I need to apply something else beforehand?

Comment: You need to add a curve object to make a curve modifier work

Comment: Like a cylinder? I've tried that shape as well and got the same result.

Comment: like a Curve > Circle

Comment: You need to create a curve object before you can assign the curve modifier to your mesh.

Answer (score 0):

curve: You found in: add-> Curve -> Like this image[image]

but, I think you want to model your object right?

Comment: Yeah I want to physically curve the object rather than drag vertex parts tediously.

Comment: depends on what you really want you can use the simple deform modifier or use sculpt mode https://prnt.sc/xy6cyo  https://prnt.sc/xy6ee6